# How can I query child entities from parent JHipster 4.6 Elastic

Tags: jhipster, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a parent child relation ship.

```
@Entity
**@Table(name = "candidate")**
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "candidate",type = "candidate")
public class Candidate implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
private Long id;

**@OneToMany(mappedBy = "candidate")
@Field(type= FieldType.Nested)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<CandidateEducation> educations = new HashSet<>();**
```

I am able to save the data in Spring elastic using JHipster.

However when I search for candidate using its id in using candidateSearchRepository the result does not return the associated educations.

```
public interface CandidateSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Candidate, Long> {
}
```

The other way works fine i.e. if I search for candidate Id in education document candidate document is embedded in the response.

```
public interface CandidateEducationSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<CandidateEducation, Long> {
}
```

I want to retrieve all associated child entities for the parent. i.e. using candidate id retrieve associated education entities.

Comment: by default all relations in jhipster are lazy loaded, have you tried to specify a fetch type in a repository query?

Comment: Thanks for giving direction on this. I looked up spring elastic data documentation but could not find a way to do this. Is there an example you can share. Am sure you did not mean to add Fetchtype in the entity class right ?

Comment: @Abhi did you find a solution for this?